# How to run Xcode application via apple devices?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am trying to run my Xcode application using real device. I haven't Apple developer account but I need to run and test my application by connecting my device.

This is the development environment I am using right now

```
 1. Xcode 6.4
 2. iOS  8.4
 3. iPod touch 6th generation (iOS 8.4)
```

**FYI** : before *Xcode 6.4* version I had successfully worked without apple account by using real device but now I cant, I dont know why. Please help me to solve this issue.

I am facing Error :

> No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair)
>   matching the team ID “(null)” were found. Xcode can attempt to fix
>   this issue.

Comment: FWIK without an Apple developer account you are out of luck.

Comment: Try with the jaibreak device

Comment: I mean not apple account.. we can run without paided account right?

Comment: FYI with `Xcode 7` you no longer need a paid developer account to run apps on a device